# How do I evaluate the integral $\int\sin^3x dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals, integration-by-parts

$$\int \sin^3(x)dx$$
Using integration by parts:
$$u=\sin^3(x)$$
$$u'=3\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$$ 
$$v'=1$$
$$v=x$$
Gives:
$$\int \sin^3(x)dx= \sin^3(x)\cdot x  - 3 \int \sin^2(x)\cdot cos(x)dx$$

Using:
$$t=\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\cos(x)$$
$$dt=\cos(x)dx$$

Results in:
$$=\sin^3(x)\cdot x - \sin^3(x) +C$$

I used integration by parts method

Comment: please use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, for a better formatting

Comment: $$\int \sin^3(x)\,dx = \int \sin(x)-\sin(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx = C-\cos(x)+\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(x).$$

Comment: You can probably [find a few other questions](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Csin%5E3x%20dx%24&p=1) about this integral. For example, [How to integrate $\int \sin^3 x dx$ step by step](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683050) or [Integral of $\int\sin^{3}xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1204184).

Answer (score 2):

By integration by parts you should have
$$\int \sin^3(x)dx= \sin^3(x)\cdot x  - 3 \int x\sin^2(x)\cdot \cos(x)dx.$$
The integral can be done in this way:
$$\int \sin^3(x)\, dx=\int (1-\cos^2(x))\sin(x)\, dx=\int \sin(x) dx+\int \cos^2(x)D(\cos(x))\, dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know it's a correct way to solve it but I'm trying to find where did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Natalia By integration by parts you should have
$$\int \sin^3(x)dx= \sin^3(x)\cdot x  - 3 \int x\sin^2(x)\cdot \cos(x)dx.$$

Comment: @Natlia Is it clear now where you made the mistake?

Comment: I get it now thanks! What a stupid mistake I made

Comment: You forgot, Natalia, to use $uv- \int vu'$, in particular, you forgot to include v = x$ in the remaining integral.

Answer (score 1):

If you use $u=\sin^3x$ and $v=1$, you get into big troubles, because the next integral you need to compute is
$$
\int 3x\sin^2x\cos x\,dx
$$
which is not at all easier than the one you started from.

If you really want to do it by parts, consider $u=\sin^2x$ and $v=\sin x$, so you get
\begin{align}
I&=\int\sin^3x\,dx \\
&=-\sin^2x\cos x+\int2\sin x\cos^2x\,dx \\
&=-\sin^2x\cos x+2\int\sin x\,dx-2\int\sin^3x\,dx \\
&=-\sin^2x\cos x-2\cos x-2I
\end{align}
that gives
$$
I=\frac{1}{3}(-\sin^2x\cos x-2\cos x)+c=\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3x-3\cos x)
$$

Much easier is to consider
$$
\int\sin^3x\,dx=\int(1-\cos^2x)\sin x\,dx\underset{u=\cos x}{=}\int(u^2-1)\,du
$$
which works alike for every odd power of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\sin^3x=\frac{3\sin{x}-\sin3x}{4},$$
but the Robert Z's and the  Jack D'Aurizio's way is more nicer.

In your solution you need to write $x$ inside the last integral.
This is your mistake.

Because $\int{v'}dx=\int1dx=x+C$.

Comment: @Natalia I fixed my post. See now.

Comment: Oh yes I get it now, how could I not see it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\sin^3x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\sin^2x\,\mathrm{d}(\sin x)\ldots$$

using power-reducation formula you can continue without by parts

remember that $$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks you for the answer!

Comment: $d(\sin x)=\cos x\,dx$